# cocoa icu document

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uiwebview, icu

I want to have syntax highlighting in UIWebView. I have heard about Cocoa icu, but there're no documents I've found from Googling.

Can somebody give me some information??

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it turned into RegexKit, but i do see that the link on http://site.icu-project.org/related is stale.

I wrote a small wrapper for a couple parts of ICU into Cocoa. Basically, you can call the ICU C (not C++) interfaces from objective C.

ICU itself doesn't do syntax hilighting, were you looking for the regex portion?